# Sort an array containing combination of only three numbers say 0s, 1s & 2s

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

How can I sort an array of 0s 1s & 2s with the best complexity?

`arr = {0,2,1,0,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,2,2,1}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here an alternative `O(n)` solution :

At most, you'll iterate twice over the elements of the array. First iteration would swap each `0` it finds with the first non-zero element of the array. Second iteration swap any `1` it finds with the first index of the array containing `2`.

Answer (score 10):

Use [*counting sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort): count how many zeros, ones, and twos you've got, and then write these numbers back into the array, over the original values. This takes `O(n)` time:

```
int[] counts = new int[] {0, 0, 0};
for (int n : arr)
    counts[arr[i]]++;
int p = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 3 ; i++) {
    while (counts[i] != 0) {
        arr[p++] = i;
        counts[i]--;
    }
}
```